# How to GET json data and image file in multipart/mixed with persistent connection API?

Tags: c#, json, .net, webrequest

I want to get json data and image file with the same WEB API.

For example,
API : http://127.0.0.1/api/alertstream
After calling this URI, a persistent connection is set up between the device and the platform.
This API will not be closed unless you close it yourself.

```
Example:

--MIME_boundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Length: 650

{
Here is the json data.
}

--MIME_boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Picture"; filename="Picture.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 82909

Here is the picture binary data.

.........more (Maybe json data . Maybe picture data.)
```

This is my code

But it only can get json data to analysis,I want to save the image file when the API sends me an image file.

```
private Boolean alertStream_status = false;
private WebRequest request;

public void alertStream() //stream API
{
        request = WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1/api/alertstream");
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "admin");
        request.BeginGetResponse(ar =>
        {
            var req = (WebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
            using (var response = req.EndGetResponse(ar))
            {
                int BYTES_TO_READ = 200000;
                var buffer = new byte[BYTES_TO_READ];
                using (Stream sm = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(sm))
                    {
                        string[] key = new string[] { "MIME_boundary", "Content-Type", "Content-Length", "Content-Disposition" };
                        // This loop goes as long as the api is streaming
                        int json_check = 0;
                        string json_obj = null;

                        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            if (alertStream_status)
                            {
                                var line = reader.ReadLine();

                                if (line == "{") json_check++;
                                if (json_check != 0) build_json(ref json_obj, line, ref json_check);
                                else
                                {
                                    Boolean check_line = false;
                                    for (int test_key = 0; test_key < 4; test_key++)
                                    {
                                        check_line = line.ToLower().Contains(key[test_key].ToLower());
                                        if (check_line) break;
                                    }
                                    if (!check_line && line != null)
                                    {
                                        //else data (picture)
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                reader.Dispose();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, request);
    }

    private void build_json(ref string json,string line,ref int json_check)
    {
        if (line == "}") json_check--;
        line = Regex.Replace(line, @"\s", "");
        if (json_check != 0) json = json + line;
        else
        {
            json = json + line;
            Console.WriteLine(json);  //debug use
            try
            {
                Json_Type_class.alertinfo content_body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Json_Type_class.alertinfo>(json);
                ProcessAlarm(content_body); //This place is a function to analyze json.
            }
            catch
            { 

            }
            json = null;
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me? Thank you very much
Sorry my english is not good,

Comment: It's very unclear what _actual issue_ you're facing. You've posted code, but what about it is "bad"? Are you getting an exception? Does the code not do what you expect it to do? Also, you seem to be parsing JSON manually, you may want to invest in using a library to parse the JSON for you into an easier to use object, like Newtonsoft.Json (which I see you're doing elsewhere in your code) or the System.Text.Json library.

Comment: Sorry! I may not have explained my question well.
My code can works, but it can only parse json, but not image files.
The `var line = reader.ReadLine();` in the code will always print the transmitted stream line by line, so my code can parse json from `{` `}` but can not parse binary image files.